# Get data from file_get_contents and redirect if "Y"

Tags: php, ip, file-get-contents

Im still new in PHP. I would like to redirect user if data from http://www.shroomery.org/ythan/proxycheck.php?ip=xxxxxx is Y and do nothing if N.
I have this code below. Not sure if correct or not. Then what should i do next?

```
<?PHP
// Function to get the client ip address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}


$userIP=get_client_ip();

$xml = file_get_contents("http://www.shroomery.org/ythan/proxycheck.php?ip=$userIP");


?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: looks like better to use `switch`

Answer (score 0):

Something like,

```
if( $xml === 'Y' )
    header('Location: http://www.something.com');
```

see, http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: you forget ' after link    header('Location: http://www.soemthing.com');
That work.. thank you

Comment: No problem. Thanks for solve my problem. That is what im looking for.